# How to serialize specific attributes of nested object in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

I have 2 entities with many to many relationship Author and Book.

Now when I serialize Book to json it provide me all fields for nested author objects.

```php
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "clean code",
    "authors": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Martin Robert "
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

But how do I make it to return only specific fields, e.g only name for each author.

I tried to add Groups to Author entity, but when I run serializer looks like groups don't apply to nested objects, because I get the same result.

```
    $book=$this->serializer->normalize($book, null, ['groups' => 'Concise']);
    $book=$this->serializer->serialize($book,'json');
```

Comment: Serializer group is the way to do it. I don"t know why in your case it seems to not work. Moreover, you don't have to "normalize" your book before "serialize". You can serialize your entities directly. Maybe it's link to your problem.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should take a look at [JMS Serializer](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer), it's a powerful library for serializing objects, and you can easily do what you're asking for using the @Groups annotation on your entities by configuring which fields should be kept in the serializing process.

**Book.php**

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

class Book {
  /** @Groups({"Concise"}) */
  private $id;

  /** @Groups({"Concise"}) */
  private $name;

  /** @Groups({"Concise"}) */
  private $authors;

  ...
}
```

If you want to retrieve authors name only when serializing the book entity, only put a @Groups annotation on the name field.

**Author.php**

```
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

class Author {
  private $id;

  /** @Groups({"Concise"}) */
  private $name;

  private $books;

  ...
}
```

**Then**

```
use JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;


$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
$context = SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('Concise'));
$json = $serializer->serialize($book, 'json', $context);
```